# React Router Dom v6 with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have upgraded to react-router-dom v6 I have been using RouteComponentProps for mapping over routes as below but was wondering how to inplement this in v6

```
<Switch>
        {routes.map((route, index) => {
            return (
                <Route
                    key={index}
                    exact={route.exact}
                    path={route.path}
                    render={(routeProps: RouteComponentProps<any>) => (
                        <route.component {...routeProps} />
                    )}
                />
            );
        })}
    </Switch>
```

I know that Switch is now replaced with Routes, but tnot sure what replaces RouteComponentProps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**react-router-dom** `6.4` recommends using `createBrowserRouter`  for web apps.  It uses the **DOM History API** to update the **URL** and manage the history stack.

```
const App = () => {


  const routes = [
    {
      path: "/",
      element: <Dashboard />,
    },
    {
      path: "/messages",
      element: <Messages />,
    },
     {
      path: "/messages/:slug",
      element: <Message />,
    }
  ];

  return <RouterProvider router={createBrowserRouter(routes)} />
};
```

Each route can define a loader function that provides data through `useLoaderData` to the root element before rendering.

```
const AppRoutes = () => {


  const routes = [
    {
      path: "/",
      element: <Dashboard />,
      loader: async () => {
         return fetch(`/api/dashoard`);
      },
    },
    {
      path: "/messages",
      element: <Messages />,
      loader: async () => {
          return fetch(`/api/messages`);
      },
    },
     {
      path: "/messages/:slug",
      element: <Message />,
      loader: async ({param}) => {
          return fetch(`/api/messages/${param.slug}`);
      },
    }
  ];

  return <RouterProvider router={createBrowserRouter(routes)} />
};
```

```
const Message = () => {
  const data = useLoaderData()
  return <p> {data.message} </p>

}
```

You probably need to use `<Suspanse>` too. It is a `built-in` react component.

```
    <Suspense>
      <RouterProvider router={createBrowserRouter(routes, { basename })} />
    </Suspense>
```

#### References

1. https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/create-browser-router
2. https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/loader
3. https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-loader-data

---

#### Original answer

Version 6 does not have `Switch` and has removed the `render` function too.

Instead of `Switch`, use `Routes`.

Intead of the `render` method, use `element` which is a `React.ReactNode` .

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard />} />
  <Route path="messages" element={<DashboardMessages />} />
  <Route path="tasks" element={<DashboardTasks />} />
  <Route path="about" element={<AboutPage />} />
</Routes>;
```

Only if `<route.component />` is a `React.ReacNode`.

```
<Routes>
  {routes.map((route, index) => {
    return (
      <Route key={index} path={route.path} element={<route.component />} />
    );
  })}
</Routes>;
```

Reference:

https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/components/route

Answer (score 0):

There is no replacement for the route props in `react-router-dom@6`. Components should instead use the React hooks:

- [useLocation](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-location)
- [useParams](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-params)
- [useNavigate](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate)

Note that there are several other new hooks in RRDv6.

Code:

```
<Routes>
  {routes.map((route) => {
    const Component: React.ReactNode | null = route.component;
    return (
      <Route
        key={route.path}
        path={route.path}
        element={<Component />}
      />
    );
  })}
</Routes>
```

If the route component is still a class component then you'll need to either convert them to function component or create your own custom `withRouter` HOC since that was also removed in v6.

Example:

```
const withRouter = Component => props => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const params = useParams();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return <Component {...props} {...{ location, params, navigate }} />;
};
```

Comment: but what about typing the state inside `useLocation` - the hook doesn't take any type arguments - so how do you specify the state / search typings inside the returned object?

Comment: @ortonomy The `location` object doesn't specify a type for `location.state`, or rather, it's typed as `unknown`.  You'll cast it to the interface/type you need in *your* code when accessing it. See [source code](https://github.com/remix-run/history/blob/main/packages/history/index.ts#L94-L117).