# Module '"react-router-dom"' has no exported member 'RouteComponentProps'. ts(2305). How to do it in RRD v6?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom, crud, react-tsx

I have a project in which I'm doing CRUD operations. I'm using React.TS. When I make function to delete a selected item then after deleting I've to navigate to home page where I'm listing my Items. I'm using 'react-router-dom' v6 but only know to import 'RouteComponentProps' from v5 and working with this. But as we know 'RouteComponentProps' is no more exist in v6. That's why I'm getting this error. Can anyone help me please. Here is my code for a specific selected item to read, delete and update it.

```
    import React, { Component, ChangeEvent } from 'react';
    import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';
    import TutorialService from '../../services/TutorialService';
    import { ITutorialData } from '../../types/tutorial.type';
    
    interface RouterProps {
      id: string
    };
    
    type Props = RouteComponentProps<RouterProps>;
    type State = {
      currentTutorial: ITutorialData,
      message: string,
    };
    
    
    export default class Tutorial extends Component<Props, State> {
      constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);
        this.onChangeTitle = this.onChangeTitle.bind(this);
        this.onChangeDescription = this.onChangeDescription.bind(this);
        this.getTutorial = this.getTutorial.bind(this);
        this.updatePublished = this.updatePublished.bind(this);
        this.updateTutorial = this.updateTutorial.bind(this);
        this.deleteTutorial = this.deleteTutorial.bind(this);
        this.state = {
          currentTutorial: {
            id: null,
            title: "",
            description: "",
            published: false,
          },
          message: "",
        };
      }
    
      componentDidMount(): void {
        this.getTutorial(this.props.match.params.id);
      };

  getTutorial(id: string) {
    TutorialService.get(id)
      .then((response: any) => {
        this.setState({
          currentTutorial: response.data,
        });
        console.log(response.date);
      }).catch((e: Error) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  };

   deleteTutorial() {
    TutorialService.remove(this.state.currentTutorial.id)
      .then((resp: any) => {
        console.log(resp.data);
        this.props.history.push("/tutorials");
      }).catch((e: Error) => {
        console.log(e);
      })
  } 

render() {
    return (
      <div>Tutorial</div>
    )
  }
}
```

Now in deleteTutorial() I'm navigating/pushing on `/tutorials` and in `componentDidMount()` I'm passing 'id' in `getTutorial()` and both depends upon `RouteComponentProps` which giving me error. Anyone help me please to write this code in `react-router-dom` v6.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Router Dom v6 with Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72309882/react-router-dom-v6-with-typescript)

Comment: RRDv6 doesn't have any route props. Anything passed as props in v5 are now exclusively accessed via React hooks in v6.